# How I can check with react-router-dom 6.0.2 v

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I used this code to check if the user sign in or not in react-router-dom 5.3.0v but this code doesn't work with me in 6.0.2v, what instead of?

```
  <Route
          exact
          path="/"
          render={() => {
              return (
                this.props.loading === true ?
                <Redirect to="/login" /> :
                <Redirect to="/home" /> 
              )
          }}
        />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abstract the anonymous component into an actual React component and render as JSX. Remember that the `Navigate` component replaced the `Redirect`, and the `Route` components render their components on the `element` prop.

```
const AuthRedirect = ({ loading }) => (
  <Navigate to={loading ? "/login" : "/home"} replace />
);
```

...

```
<Route path="/" element={<AuthRedirect loading={this.props.loading} />} />
```